# Find Name of current Route in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I need to know name of current Route in [Ember](http://www.emberjs.com) from controller.after searching i find this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180082/ember-js-rc1-get-name-of-route) and this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302463/get-current-route-name-in-ember) but `this.routeName` and `this.get('currentPath')` dosent work for me.my Ember version is `1.1.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way i know how to do this is to require `application` controller like this.

```
App.AfterController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  init: function() {
    alert('Current route is ' + this.get('controllers.application.currentPath'));
    this._super();
  }
});
```